# Как создать блок, который всегда прижат к низу экрана

Tags: html, javascript, css

Нужно создать блок шириной 200px, который прижат к низу... который всегда виден внизу экрана, даже если идет прокрутка страницы

Comment: что вы [нагуглили](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83) по этому поводу?

Comment: чтобы увидеть футер, страницу нужно прокрутить вниз, а мне надо сделать так, чтобы этот блок был всегда виден внизу, как бы плавал

Comment: @Vadizar, я не считаю, что это дубликат. Пользователю во втором вопросе нужен был другой эффект

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="x"></div>

<style>
    #x{
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        width:200px
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!!!!!

Comment: может хоть некоторые ответы на ваши вопросы вы будете принимать?

Answer (score 0):

В CSS задавать для этого блока:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```

Это позиционирование элемента относительно экрана

Comment: Обьясните, пожалуйста, что дают данные стили и зачем их писать вместе?

    left: 0;
    right:0;